# If something is halfway in a bag of holding... what happens to it?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

If I put something in the bag of holding and get attacked, and drop it, so it's laying half in and half out of the bag.. what happens to the item?

Meaning if I'm putting a long piece of lumber inside the bag of holding, and drop it before I finish putting the lumber inside, does the lumber get bisected? Or does it just hang out there. Is there a spot in the center not in the portal, but not out of it?

Comment: note: "Limbo" in D&D (at least 5e) is its own plane, the plane of ultimate chaos, home to the Githzerai, Slaadi, and a few others. Using the phrase "to be in limbo" could, therefore, be confusing to some, and is best avoided.

Comment: I changed it to accommodate this.

Comment: I'm mainly asking if the mouth of the bag of  holding would destroy, bisect, cut, or hurt the item in any way. 

Its not the item that i'm worried about. its the bag itself. Also, the question prior was if it could be carried that way, and if you read the comments, was not fully answered.

Comment: @Thatguy the edit you made (a) does, indeed, pose a novel question, and (b) invalidates the existing answer. As such I'm going to revert the edit, re-close the question as a duplicate, and ask/encourage you to pose your new question in a new post. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

### They both fall down

A [Bag of Holding](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Bag%20of%20Holding#content) is not a “portal” - it’s a bag. Albeit a bag that’s bigger on the inside than it is on the outside. Something that’s half in and half out behaves the same way as it would in any other sack.

Comment: It is not simply "just bigger on the inside" it is an extra-dimensional space meaning things "in the bag" are not currently on the plane where the bag is. The interactions with other extradimensional spaces and the rules call out in Curse of Strahd on escaping the Demiplane of Dread are a testament to that. The rest of the answer is correct (the opening isn't a "portal" like you would expect from a spell), I just wanted to call out that very real distinction.

Comment: but if its a normal bag, and there's no portal inside of it, How does it stop the flow of air into the bag.

Comment: @Thatguy _does_ it stop the air, though?

Comment: Yes. The bag only contains 10 minutes of air. If it contained more air than that something could feasibly live in it.

Comment: @Thatguy a submarine doesn't have an infinite air supply, either. But if you rise to the surface and open the hatch, you are no longer limited by the air capacity of the submarine ;)

Comment: The bag is indeed an extradimensional space as indicated by the descriptions of the Handy Haversack and other similar items and thus the opening or at least the inner portion of the bag is a portal to that pocket dimension.